# Python dataclass with inheritance: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-dataclasses

Trying my luck with inheritance with data classes (Python 3.9.13).

Given the following:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from datetime import datetime


@dataclass()
class BookMetadata():
    '''Parent class.'''
    
    isbn: str 
    title: str 
    author: str
    publisher: str
    date_published: int
    

    def __post_init__(self):
        '''Change attributes after assignment.'''
            
        # Change date from UNIX to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
        self.date_published = datetime.fromtimestamp(int(str(self.date_published))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
      

@dataclass()
class RetailPrice(BookMetadata):
    '''Child class.'''
    
    def __init__(self, 
                 isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published,
                 price_usd, price_aud, price_eur, price_gbp) -> None:
        
        BookMetadata.__init__(isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)
        
        self.price_usd: float = price_usd
        self.price_aud: float = price_aud
        self.price_eur: float = price_eur
        self.price_gbp: float = price_gbp


    def __post_init__(self):
        self.price_usd = str(self.price_usd)
```

and the values assigned as such:

```
book1 = RetailPrice(isbn='1234-5678-9000', 
                    title='My book', 
                    author='Name Surname', 
                    publisher='My publisher',
                    date_published=1670536799, 
                    price_usd=17.99, 
                    price_aud=23.99, 
                    price_eur=15.99, 
                    price_gbp=16.99)
```

I get a `TypeError:`:
`TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'date_published'`, but this was provided in the assignment.

Is this due to the fact that the parent class has no `__init__`?

PS: this is my attempt at reproducing line 21 in the image below, having to work with data classes instead of regular classes:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a subclass of `BookMetadata` you can just initialise the superclass from child class using [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) -

```
@dataclass()
class RetailPrice(BookMetadata):
    '''Child class.'''
    
    def __init__(self, 
                 isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published,
                 price_usd, price_aud, price_eur, price_gbp) -> None:
        super().__init__(isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)
        self.price_usd: float = price_usd
        self.price_aud: float = price_aud
        self.price_eur: float = price_eur
        self.price_gbp: float = price_gbp
```

The reason for the error in your original code is because of the missing self argument to `BookMetadata.__init__()`, since you don't have an instance of `BookMetadata` class, so one argument was missing(self + 5 additional arguments, so it was giving error on the last missing argument `date_published`)

Comment: Uhm, adding a `__post_init__` method to the child class with exactly the same syntax as the parent class returns an `AttributeError`, despite that attribute being properly referenced in the code and assigned at runtime. I added `def __post_init__(self): self.price_usd = str(self.price_usd)`, but at runtime I get `AttributeError: 'RetailPrice' object has no attribute 'price_usd'`

Comment: Can you share the corresponding code? Maybe, you are trying to access some non-existing attribute? You should be able to access the super class's attributes as `self.isbn` directly for example.

Comment: Yep, look at the edited code. I think the attribute is existing, but can there be confusion between the `__post_init__` of the parent class and that of the child class?

Comment: Moving the `super().__init__(isbn, title, author, publisher, date_published)` part to below the dataclass arguments fixes the issue.

Comment: moving the `super` call below the `self.price_xxx` arguments results in the arguments of the child class not being retained, so essentially only those of the parent class are kept.

Comment: I can see `print(self.isbn, self.price_gbp)` printing alright, in both `__init__()` and `__post_init()`

Comment: They're there, but they're not printed by the console when running `book1` +enter, as if they were hidden or private?

Comment: ahh ok, you would need to update the `__repr__()` method of the class, the parent class being a dataclass would have the function which would only print its own fields, while child one would print its own ones. So you might have to redefine it on your own to include all fields.